# Swift Parse Query For Users That I Follow

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, tableview

I currently have a query that returns a table of all the users that I have on my server along with a checkmark next to their name if I follow them. Here's the code:

```
//REFRESHER
func refresh() {

    self.usernames.removeAll()
    self.userIDs.removeAll()
    self.isFollowing.removeAll()


    let query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)

        } else if let users = objects {

            //self.usernames.removeAll()
            //self.userIDs.removeAll()
            //self.isFollowing.removeAll()

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    if user.objectId != PFUser.current()?.objectId {

                        self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                        self.userIDs.append(user.objectId!)

                        let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")

                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId)

                        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

                            if let objects = objects {

                                if objects.count > 0 {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                                } else {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false

                                }

                                if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {

                                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                                    self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                                }

                            }

                        })


                    }

                }

            }
            //self.refresher.endRefreshing()

        }


    })

}
```

I'm trying to return a table with only users that I follow, however I can't seem to get it to work as my Followers class is outside of the PFUser class and thus it's difficult to append the usernames and userID's of users in the Follower's class.

My Followers class has four columns, follower and following which are the respective user ID's of each user, and then followerUsername and followingUsername which are the usernames of the respective users. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: I'm now using pointers to reference `follower` and `following` in Parse and here's how I'm trying to query the users that I'm following. This implementation isn't working so if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate it!

```
     func refresh() {

    self.usernames.removeAll()
    self.userIDs.removeAll()
    self.isFollowing.removeAll()


           let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")

           query.includeKey("following")

           query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId)


           query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

                            if error != nil {
                                print(error)

                            } else if let following = objects {

                                for object in following {

                                    if let usersFollowing = object as? PFObject {


           self.usernames.append(usersFollowing["followingUsername"] as! String)
           self.userIDs.append(usersFollowing["following"] as! String)


                            if let objects = objects {

                                if objects.count > 0 {


          self.isFollowing[usersFollowing["following"] as! String] = true

                                } else {

          self.isFollowing[usersFollowing["following"] as! String] = false

                                }

          if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {

                                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                                    self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                }
                            }
    })
}
```

**HERE ARE MY 2 TABLES**

[userPost Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ojc.png)

[Follower Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rylG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is ridiculously inefficient with the nested queries and table reloads... Once you get any sizable number of users, you're performing way too many queries and hitting that table refresh hard.

You want a table that just has  all of the users your current user is following?  Your Followers table should use pointers instead of object ids, then you can just use the `includeKeys` method on queries to have it fetch the `following` field of the `Followers` object, and find all objects where `follower` is equal to the current user.

With the IDs, you could get away with doing a matchesKeyInQuery method, with a `Followers` query where `follower` equals the current user's ID, and the User query has matchesKeyInQuery where the key is objectId, queryKey is following, and query is the Follower query.  But pointers are the proper way to do join tables, not storing Ids.

You could also look into Relations, which may be a good fit for tracking users that you follow.

Comment: Okay well I'm definitely gonna need efficiency since I'm expecting to have a substantial user base. I'm not very familiar with pointers so could you give me an idea of how I need to change my code to accomplish this most efficiently? I'll be implementing this follower/following in multiple places on the app so it's important that I get it right. You've helped answer some of my questions before so thank you so much!

Comment: I set up pointers in my Parse backend for followers and following, however I can't get it to save the currentuserID and following UserID to my pointers in parse when a user is tapped in my table.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a string to the value? Create a shell pointer. PFUser* following = [PFUser objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:followingId];   PFUser *follower = [PFUser currentUser];

Comment: I just need it to save the objectID of the current user as well as the user at [indexpath.row] which should just be strings. It saved perfectly when I had strings instead of pointers as the follower and following columns in Parse, but now doesn't do anything as I've changed them to pointers

Comment: I figured saving and deleting pointers now, my new UPDATE above shows how I'm trying to query only the users that I follow with pointers now. It still isn't working so is there any way you can point out how I might get this to work?

Comment: You're doing the same thing, trying to query against a pointer class using a string.  You have to create a shell id if you don't already have access to the object id.  but in general, `var user = PFUser()` `user.objectId = objectId`  `query.whereKey("userKey", equalTo:user)`  In your case, just change `currentUser()?.objectId` to `currentUser()?`

Comment: It takes an extra line of code or so as you have to create "shell objects" with just the class and id, instead of using the id alone, but it makes things way neater and cleaner when you account for not having to then build those objects and create nested queries with the results.

Comment: Still not really understanding, it's not creating a shell id by simply saying user.objectId = objectId that just creates an error. Changing `currentUser()?.objectId` to `currentUser()?` helped, however `self.userIDs.append(usersFollowing["following"] as! String)` is now giving me a Sigbert error, as it gives me everything about the user linked from the pointer I made for `following` in my class when I try printing it. I only want the objectId from that pointer but I don't know how to only access that.

Comment: it looks like `usersFollowing` is an instance of `Followers`. You can't downcast that to a string.  `let followingUser = usersFollowing["following"] as! PFObject` and `self.userIDs.append(followingUser.objectId)` should work, but then you've just got the ID. That's fine as long as it's what you need there, the importance of the pointer was to make querying easier and more efficient. You just have to make sure you know when you're using / needing the object as opposed to the id.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice :) Now don't forget to change variable names because they don't make quite as much sense anymore lol.  Much easier to do that as you go in dev than try to rework it later if you end up making the project collaborative or something... Shell objects are powerful, FYI.  You create an instance of the object with the class name, then set the objectId.  You don't magically get the data (though you can now call fetch on that object to get it), but you can add / update fields and save it, and just those fields get updated! Or use it as a query constraint. attach it to another object as a pointer.

Comment: I've definitely recognized the power of pointers. Do you recommend I make pointers in my other classes as well since I have to relate them with one another? Another example I'm working on now is having the feed include posts from only users you follow, so I'd create a pointer in my userPost class to followers so that I can access only posts from those that I follow

Comment: Question: Do pointers always point to objectID's for the class you're pointing to? Or can I make them point to any column in the class I'm pointing to?

Comment: Look up the concept of JoinTables. It's a common practice akin to what you're looking for. Steer clear of arrays of pointers - they're awful to work with, I've learned from experience. Relations are another good option for many:many relationships, though I have less experience with them. Lots of situations can be simplified with pointers, but keep in mind that when a Parse object is saved, it also saves its pointers, so going overboard with them can lead to some other interesting problems.

Comment: Okay, wish I could use SQL but Parse is NonSQL from what I've read. Haven't seen a whole lot on how to JoinTables.... I just need to be able to be able to match `user objectId` columns for different classes.... however the problem with pointers right now is that I can only point to the `User` class since it's the only one that's `objectId` for each row is = to the `user's objectId`. Other classes have their own `objectId` for each row that isn't the same as the `User` objectId, and thus a pointer to that class using a `user objectID` won't give me any data

Comment: Is there a way to make pointers that pick up on some other kind of information, not just objectId for each row in the class? For example, if I wanted to make a pointer from `userPost` to `Followers` class, and the pointer is the `userobjectID` from `userPost` which is supposed to point to the corresponding objectId that matches in the `following` column in the `Follower` class

Comment: Yeah you have to use the objectId of whatever object you're trying to do a pointer to.  You can include nested pointers, though.  Say you have classes ClassA, ClassB with a pointer classA to a ClassA object, and ClassC, which has a pointer classB to a ClassB object. You can do `var query = new Parse.Query("ClassC"); query.include("classB").include("classB.classA");` and the results will contain ClassC objects, with their full ClassB objects, as well as the full ClassA object on ClassB.

Comment: Okay that's helpful, but I still have the problem of not being able to match objectId's. Check out the pictures of my `userPost` and `Follower` tables that I just added above. What I need is a `userPost` query where `userId` = `following` from the `Follower` table where `following` is the userId of all the users that I follow. This will result in only the posts from users that I follow. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Since you use an id instead of a pointer on the `userPost` table, you can't, but you could use a query if you change it to a pointer. Let's say you use a `user` field as a User pointer.  I'm more familiar with JS, so you'll have to port this to Swift.  `var followingQuery = new Parse.Query("Followers").equalTo("follower", Parse.User.currentUser()); var userPostQuery = new Parse.Query("userPost").matchesKeyInQuery("user", "following", followingQuery);`  `matchesKeyInQuery` takes in the key to match in the query you call it on, the key in another class, and a query for that other class.